# How to validate individual fields on button click in angular js as we do in JQuery

Tags: html, angularjs

As we have number of input fields and there are some fields as required example:

```
<input placeholder="Role" type="text" required/>
<span ng-show="Role" class="text-danger">Role is required.</span>
<input placeholder="Title" type="text" required/>
etc..
<button type="button" ngclick="Savereferences()">Save</button>
```

Now i want to validate this fields on click of Save button in angular js, Can any one help me out how to do this.

Comment: You are missing `ng-model` on inputs. You can use them to validate

Answer (score 0):

```
<input placeholder="Role" ng-model="Role" type="text" required/>
<span ng-show="RoleMsg" class="text-danger">Role is required.</span>
<input placeholder="Title" ng-model="Title" type="text" required/>
etc..
<button type="button" ngclick="Savereferences()">Save</button>
```

JS Code for validating Role

```
$scope.Savereferences=function(){
  if($scope.Role){
                  $scope.RoleMsg=true;
                }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this...using ng-required and form

```
    <form role="form" id="form" name="form" class="form-horizontal">
      <input placeholder="Role" id="role" name="role" type="text" ng-required="true"/>
      <span ng-show="form.role.$error.required">Role is required.</span>
      //Same as other field
      <button type="button" ng-disabled="!form.$valid" ngclick="Savereferences()">Save</button>
    </form>
```